# How do I force an SVG to fill its container horizontally?

Tags: html, css, svg, fill

We're developing a site for a client who needs to use SVGs to simulate the top/bottom of devices around pictures and videos. I'm running into an issue (almost exclusively on iPad, but it does happen to some extent on other browsers, sometimes) where the SVG is failing to fill space properly. When the browser scales, the SVG will scale as well, but it will leave small gaps at various sizes. I can't get the SVG to fill its container edge-to-edge reliably.

I've tried adding the SVG through an image tag, object tag, and I've tried hardcoding the SVG data into the pages. I've also tried a few different ways to force the SVG to fill that space, and every version of what I've tried has netted the same results.

Here's a screenshot that illustrates the problem:

[image]

[image]

And here's the code for the above: https://codepen.io/the_pm/pen/dypVMMB - I added a version with the SVG hardcoded into place. The hardcoded SVG works in more browsers than the  version (note that the SVG doesn't have any style applied to it). But they both still display gapping on iPad/Safari, which I thought the absolute positioning would fix, but it doesn't.

As stated, I've tried linking the SVG, and I've tried adding the SVG code directly into the page, without any difference in display. Here are a couple CSS methods I used to try to force the desired behavior.

METHOD 1:

```
.topper {
    font-size:0 ; /* prevents gapping due to font descenders */
    height:auto ;
    padding-bottom:3.62% ; /* height/width of image */
    position:relative ;
    width:100%
}
.topper img {
    height:100% ;
    left:0 ;
    position:absolute ;
    top:0 ;
    width:100%
    /* also tried bottom:0 and right:0 instead of height:100% and width:100% - no luck */
}
```

METHOD 2:

```
.topper {
    background:url('path/to/image.svg') center top no-repeat ;
    background-size:100% 100% ;
    font-size:0 ;
    height:auto ;
    padding-bottom:3.62% ;
    width:100%
}
```

I have tried at least a dozen variations of the code above, but the result is the same as you see in the codepen.

Any assistance would be most appreciated!

Comment: Your code does not describe the whole page, and the screenshot does not show the buggy behavior, but you expect us to understand the problem? We'll also need the source code of the SVG to understand this. Finally, how do you know the SVG is the problem, and not whatever it is supposed to be aligned to? Raster images tend to round to full pixels, while SVGs have no need to do so.

Comment: Hi ccprog - I've edited the original post. I replaced the screenshot with two others showing what happens. I isolated the issue with CodePen, but the original picture I linked should have made those gaps clear (they were highlighted with red lines). The issue does not happen with other image types, and the object to which it needs to be aligned is irrelevant. It simply need to fill the container the same way any other block-level element would fill the space it is given. Does this help clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are experiencing a rounding problem you have no real control over. Browsers per specification are at large how to handle those. You are using a SVG that is much wider than high. That has the mathematical consequence that, when scaling it, rounding its size to full pixels will result in a significant change of the aspect ratio.

Now SVGs react differently to changes in aspect ratio than other images. Browsers always recompute raster images so they will fill all the pixels, even to the price of  distorting them a bit. SVGs act on an attribute [preserveAspectRatio](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute) that defaults to the value `"xMidYMid meet"`. Glossing over what this exactly means, what it amounts to is comparable to the CSS `"contain"` value.

When scaling your image, the act of rounding a height value *down* can easily result in the width, when computing exactly, lacking more than 1px. Here is an example: Let the width available be 982px. The computed height to preserve aspect ratio would be 78 / 2160 * 982 = 35.4611px. Now, if the browser rounds down, the exact width would be 2160 / 78 * 35 = 969.231px. That would be displayed as a gap of ca. 6.6px on each side.

The obvious way to counteract this is to set the attribute to `preserveAspectRatio="none"`. (I've taken the liberty to rewrite your SVG, simplifying it and improving readability.)

```css
svg {
    display: block;
    width: 982px;
    height: 35px;
    background: green;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 2160 78">
  <rect x="1" y="1" width="2158" height="120" rx="30" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-width:2" />
  <circle r="9" cx="62" cy="40" />
  <circle r="9" cx="97" cy="40" />
  <circle r="9" cx="132" cy="40" />
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 2160 78" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <rect x="1" y="1" width="2158" height="120" rx="30" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-width:2" />
  <circle r="9" cx="62" cy="40" />
  <circle r="9" cx="97" cy="40" />
  <circle r="9" cx="132" cy="40" />
</svg>
```

Comment: This is a great explanation - thank you so much! I figured there was a rounding issue (it makes sense just looking at what's happening), but I didn't realize preserveAspectRatio was the instruction preventing me from forcing the SVG to fill that space. The SVGs are supplied by the client, and they will need to drop them into place without using code. So I've asked them to reexport them with preserveAspectRatio set to 'none'. Hopefully this will allow one of my previous code attempts to give them the desired result. Regardless, this is a great answer - hopefully useful for others too.